# How to list all test categories from Mstest dll?

Tags: mstest

We are using MsTest for our automation tests. And each test has one or couple of categories. Is it possible to get list of all categories from my compiled mstest dll to construct a command line for tests execution? Pretend that I have only dll and do not know any of categories attached to tests.

Comment: No this is not possible with mstest.exe/vstest.console.exe command line. However, it should not be difficult to write a small program that uses System.Reflection APIs and lists all `TestCategory` values.